# Why am I getting different outputs for the same dataset?

Tags: python, tensorflow, machine-learning, recurrent-neural-network

This code is to try to predict the future price of a cryptocurrency. When I feed it data, it outputs different things every time. Why is this?

Link to full code: https://pastebin.com/cEfDCL8H

This code outputs what seems random, and I can't figure out why.

```
x,y = preprocess_df(test_df)

model = tf.keras.models.load_model('models/RNN_Final-15-0.972.model')

prediction = model.predict(x)

print("15 Min Prediction(0): " + str(CATEGORIES[np.argmax(prediction[0])]))
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

While Neural networks initialization, random weights are assigned. This produces differences in the final output. To avoid it, you can use a random seed so every time the same random weights are applied.

For example:
You need to set the seed in all your needed variables, as explained [here](https://medium.com/@ODSC/properly-setting-the-random-seed-in-ml-experiments-not-as-simple-as-you-might-imagine-219969c84752):

```
# Set a seed value
seed_value= 12321 
import os

# 1. Set `PYTHONHASHSEED` environment variable at a fixed value
os.environ['PYTHONHASHSEED']=str(seed_value)

# 2. Set `python` built-in pseudo-random generator at a fixed value
import random
random.seed(seed_value)

# 3. Set `numpy` pseudo-random generator at a fixed value
import numpy as np
np.random.seed(seed_value)

# 4. Set `tensorflow` pseudo-random generator at a fixed value
import tensorflow as tf
tf.set_random_seed(seed_value)

# 5. For layers that introduce randomness like dropout, make sure to set seed values 

model.add(Dropout(0.25, seed=seed_value))
```

Comment: I am still getting random results after adding
from numpy.random import seed
seed(1)
tf.random.set_seed(2)

Comment: @LawnmoersTheEpicGamer I updated the answer, please check it.

Comment: OK makes sense I will retrain my model and get back to you with the results

Comment: After retraining its still inconsistant

Comment: @LawnmoersTheEpicGamer you have to set seed before every process that involves randomness, for example, before ``random.shuffle``  in line 70 and 71.

Comment: ah ok makes a lot of sense It works now. Thanks

Comment: I am happy it helped. :)